# use Span inside of Parallel.For loop

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I am using Span to cast a float array to a byte array. Using a normal for loop is no problem, but for the amount of numbers I have, I need to parallelize my code, so I ended up using Parallel.For. The problem is that I can't use the Span inside this loop.
This is my code:

```
Span<float> floats = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, float>(posColBuffer);
Parallel.For(0, posColBuffer.Length/4, i=>
{

    var scalar = calcScalar(i);
    float color = calcColor(i);

    var id0 = 3 * i;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        floats[i+j] = directions[id0 + j] * scalar;
        floats[colorOffset + i+j] = color;
    }
});
```

The Error the IDE tells me is "Cannot use local variable 'floats' of byref-like type 'Span' inside lambda expression"

I tried putting the constructing of the Span inside the Parallel.For, but that did not work. It showed no error but it never exited the parallel for loop.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: creating the span inside the loop is the approach I would try. If this is any kind of image-data you should probably process rows of pixels in the parallel loop instead of individual pixels. There is a risk that the parallelization overhead exceed any possible gains for very small loop bodies. So my guess is that it never exits because it is just much slower.

Comment: Surely the index for `floats[i+j]` is going to go out of range? When `i == posColBuffer.Length/4 - 1`

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, that was the problem. It didn't throw an out of bounds error, so I didn't notice. Thanks. If you post this as answer, I can accept it

Comment: Where does `posColBuffer` come from?

Comment: It is a class variable. A byte[] that is used elsewhere, but has to be altered by writing float values to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Span` is stack-only datastructure and by design it is guaranteed to remain on stack and can not leave it. You can move the cast inside the `For`:

```
Parallel.For(0, posColBuffer.Length/4, i=>
{
    Span<float> floats = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, float>(posColBuffer);
    // ...
});
```

Note that you also have indexing error for `floats[i + j]` since it will overflow as mentioned by [@Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson) in the comments.

Comment: `posColBuffer` is clearly a `Span<byte>` so something else is needed to create it.

Comment: posColBuffer is a large byte[]